# how to retrieve google map custom marker icons/images and show up in a dialog

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I have used database to retrieve images and then converted to BitmapDescriptorFactory for setting up as google map marker. Now I am trying to retrieve these images to show them in a dialog/modal. can anyone suggest me the approach on retrieving the already set custom map markers and then show these in a dialog/ modal.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you can get the icon from a marker that is already on a map. However, you could make a Map(data structure) of markers to icons when you generate the markers, so you can find the right icon that way.